# Does "setup iad network" means I do not need to write ad. support code?

Tags: ios, app-store, iad

When I released my app to appstore. I saw "setup iad network" button.
I clicked the button and saw intructions.
My English is not so good, so it seems you can add iad support in your app without adding extra code.

I have add iad support code in my app.
So do I need to setup iad network?

I am a little confused.
Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1):

Adding iAd in your application allows the app to show the ads, and `Setup iAD Network` for the app means configure what you want to show on the ad.

Please refer https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/16_iAdNetwork/iAdNetwork.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011225-CH8-SW1